# Python create a dictionary with 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, numpy, runtime-error

I have an empty 'numpy.ndarray'

```
import numpy as np
my_grid =  np.zeros((5, 5))

parse = "max","min","avg"
```

I wish to create a dictionary where each element of parse is the "Key"

from collections import defaultdict

```
GridMetric = dict()
for arg in parse:
    GridMetric[arg].append(my_grid)
```

but i get this error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<editor selection>", line 3, in <module>
KeyError: 'max'
```

Comment: You can't use a numpy array as the key of a dictionary (just like you can't use a list or other mutable object).

Comment: Would you give an *exact* code which produces this error, so that we see exactly what is `parse` here.

Comment: Do you want to create a separate dictionary "for each element of parse" or do you want to create dictionary in which items in parse are keys, and the values are ... what?

Comment: parse is the key. Sorry if i explain bad the question

Comment: And what do you want the values to be?

Comment: value is "my_grid". Each my_grid for each element of parse

Comment: @Zhenya all code is there.

Comment: So every key (different elements of the list, `parse`) will have the same value (the same array, my_grid)?

Comment: @user2074981 yes you get it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25474/discussion-between-user2074981-and-gianni)

Comment: It looks like you want `GridMetric = defaultdict(list)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is a dictionary whose keys are the different elements of the list called parse and whose values are all the same array, then the following changes to your code should work:

```
import numpy as np
my_grid =  np.zeros((5, 5))

parse = ["max","min","avg"]

d = {}
for arg in parse:
    d[arg] = my_grid
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?  You said "you get it" when I wrote "every key (different elements of the list, parse) will have the same value (the same array, my_grid)?"  In what way does the code provided not do that for you?

Comment: i got always Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<editor selection>", line 3, in <module>
KeyError: 'max' becose i need parse as "max", "min", "avg"

Comment: @Gianni: that's because you imported defaultdict from collections, but aren't using it -- your object is a dict, although it looks like you want `defaultdict(list)`, and so there's none of the default-creation behaviour.  You say you want the grid to be the value, but instead you're going to have values which are lists, the first element of which is `my_grid`.

Comment: @user2074981: I suspect the OP really wants `my_grid.copy()`, even though I agree that you asked exactly this question -- whether he wanted each value to be the same array -- and he said yes.

Comment: @DSM It's true. I forgot GridMetric =defaultdict(list) and I made this mistake. Sorry and thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

my_grid =  np.zeros((5, 5))

parse = ["max","min","avg"]


for arg in parse:
    dict(parse=my_grid)

print(d)
```